# Spring Boot Bad Request while sending post request with inside class on @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I get bad request while using a nested class as a @RequestBody using postman. Is it my json? am i missing something? or this is a wrong implementation? This is my first time using a nested class for @RequestBody.

this is my class:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CreateOrder {
    @NotNull
    private final String recipientName;
    @NotNull
    private final OrderAddress address;
    @NotNull
    private final List<OrderItem> items;

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class OrderItem{
        @NotNull
        private final Product product;
        @NotNull
        private final int quantity;
    }

    @Getter
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Product{
        @NotNull
        private final Integer id;
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/v1/orders")
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Data<CreateOrderResponse>> createOrder(@RequestBody CreateOrder createOrder){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Data<>(orderService.createOrder(createOrder)), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{orderID}")
    public ResponseEntity<Data<GetOrderResponse>> getOrder(@PathVariable("orderID")UUID orderID){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Data<>(orderService.getOrder(orderID)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is my json:

```
{
    "recipientName": "TEST",
    "address": {
        "street": "Street AB",
        "city": "City A",
        "postalCode": "30001",
        "detail": "Block A"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "product": {
                "id": 1
            },
            "quantity": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need default constructors for the CreateOrder Model and its inner classes. You can use the @NoArgsConstructor annotation from Lombok to avoid having to have the boilerplate in your code. However, since your all your fields are final there will be 'Variable might not have been initialized' errors, so you will need to remove the final keyword from each field.